# Transcript of This Ven. Fulton Sheen Talk on the Christian Laity?

Tags: catholicism, resource-request, internet, laity, fulton-sheen

The talk given by Ven. Fulton Sheen in the following link pertains to the laity:

- [**Confirmation** - Venerable Bishop Fulton J. Sheen (YouTube video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Gm3X1vJNZU)

It begins as follows:

“... The greatest untapped reservoir of spiritual power is to be found in the Christian laity.”

I would like to obtain a transcript of the audio, which is entitled *Confirmation*.

QUESTION: Does anyone know if a transcript of this audio is available online? I have been able to locate other transcripts of Ven. Sheen, but not this one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You may find the transcript of the audio at the [Fulton Sheen Bible Studies: Lesson 27 – Confirmation](https://theuniversalway.com/fulton-sheen-bible-studies/lesson-27/).

Comment: Welcome to C.SE and thank you for your contribution.  To the one who voted it down, this is the right answer.

Comment: Is it possible to obtain transcripts of each of the Lessons?  I have found a subscription site online for 300 audios, but I cannot seem to find one for written transcripts of his audios. Your posted answer is most helpful. (I have not found a way to obtain, say Lesson 26 or others.)